# How can I make a mechanical cat purr?

Tags: foley

I'm trying to make a cat purr noise but I'd like to do it more mechanically than using a sound file.  It needs to fit into a box you can hold in your hand.
I'm thinking of using a slow motor with a fan that flaps against a serrated edge but how can I get it low hertz like a cat? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: If the pitch is too high, the obvious answer is to slow the motor down. If you can't do that, try slowing the audio file after it is recorded.

Comment: Thank you. The motor needs to be fast enough to buzz like a purr, if I slow it down it won't  work. I'm hoping to do it without using an audio file at all, just a purely mechanical purr.

Comment: Slow it, and add more spokes to the fan. Then it can buzz but be lower in frequency

Comment: Ah,  genius idea. Thank you!  Do you know of any materials that sound deeper than others? Metal is a bit pingy.

Comment: "*How can I make a mechanical cat purr?*" Stroke its mechanical fur. Were did you get a mechanical cat ?

Answer (score 1):

I made a tutorial on how to make a cat purr with FL Studio, maybe it can help you

todo:

- get a growl synth for the purr that is not heard constantly, chop the sound so the purring effect
- get a white noise and filter it to sound like breathing, automate the volume
- get a sawy base that
  sounds like a car engine for the constant, lower purr filter it to
  sound like "voice"